# Find the number of occurrences of a number matching 7 digits in a string with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I trying to find the number of occurrences an order number (always 7 digits), i have a multiple line text field which allows users to paste in details of an order or order within the field, the issue is when trying to capture the amount of order withing field, Example:
​3284764 loading Friday(requested 5/10/16) 
63CS – 152GG– covered on SA5

3284765 loading Friday(requested 5/10/16)
240CS – 12FXNS – short
189CS  - 301GG – covered on SA5

3284766 loading Monday
240CS – 12FXNS

3284767 loading Monday
189CS  - 301GG

the solution would return 4 order #s:3284767;3284766;3284765;​3284764
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: But you are supposed to show us your solution, and people help you fix what isn't working This isn't a code writing service.

Comment: @charlietfl Is it a good practice to answer such questions or should we abstain

Comment: I apologize for not adding what i was working but here it is,

Comment: function GetOrders() {
    var str = "<div class="ExternalClass7CFD422EAB564B90AFB9FF7DF92ECF0A">
3305504
12FXNS - 120
301GG - 189
3305506
12SPRM - 180
1EBO - 42
12EBOCP - 25
3305501 
1GGH - 42
2GGH - 42
3305502
301GG - 189
2GGH - 84</div>
";
    var patt1 = /^\d{7}$/;
    var result = str.match(patt1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
}

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like this:

```js
var text = '3284764 loading Friday(requested 5/10/16) 63CS – 152GG– covered on SA5 \
3284765 loading Friday(requested 5/10/16) 240CS – 12FXNS – short 189CS - 301GG – covered on SA5 \
3284766 loading Monday 240CS – 12FXNS \
3284767 loading Monday 189CS - 301GG';
var ordersNumbers = text.match(/\d{7}/g);
console.log(ordersNumbers);
```

Comment: This suggestion did the trick, again i apologize for the incomplete question + code snipped.

Answer (score 0):

If the order code appears as the first 7 characters in each line then you can do this:

```
var orderList = [];
var arrayOfLines = document.getElementById('<textAreaID>').val().split('\n');

arrayOfLines.forEach(function (text) {
    orderList.push( text.slice(0,7) );
});

console.log( orderList.join(';'));
```